# C++ - best way to do an array of different implementations

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to practice OO design. I've made the following classes, which will eventually let a user pick a temperature unit type (like fahrenheit) from a list, and convert celcius temperatures to their chosen temperature:

TemperatureUnits.h:

```
#include "fahrenheittemperatureunit.h"
#include "kelvintemperatureunit.h"
#include "temperatureunit.h"

#include <list>

class TemperatureUnits
{
public:
    static std::list<TemperatureUnit> All();
    const static FahrenheitTemperatureUnit kFahrenheit;
    const static KelvinTemperatureUnit kKelvin;
};
```

TemperatureUnits.cpp:

```
#include "temperatureunits.h"

std::list<TemperatureUnit> TemperatureUnits::All()
{
    std::list<TemperatureUnit> units;
    units.push_back(TemperatureUnits::kFahrenheit);
    units.push_back(TemperatureUnits::kKelvin);
    return units;
}

const KelvinTemperatureUnit TemperatureUnits::kKelvin;
const FahrenheitTemperatureUnit TemperatureUnits::kFahrenheit;
```

TemperatureUnit.h

```
class TemperatureUnit
{
public:
    explicit TemperatureUnit(const std::string &name);
    virtual ~TemperatureUnit() {}

    const std::string& Name() const;
    virtual float FromCelcius(float celcius) const {return 0;}

private:
    std::string name_;
};
```

TemperatureUnit.cpp:

```
#include "temperatureunit.h"

TemperatureUnit::TemperatureUnit(const std::string &name)
    :
    name_(name)
{

}

const std::string& TemperatureUnit::Name() const
{
    return name_;
}
```

Lastly, an example subclass:

KelvinTemperatureUnit.h:

```
#include "temperatureunit.h"

class KelvinTemperatureUnit : public TemperatureUnit
{
public:
    explicit KelvinTemperatureUnit();
    virtual float FromCelcius(float celcius) const;
};
```

KelvinTemperatureUnit.cpp:

```
#include "kelvintemperatureunit.h"

KelvinTemperatureUnit::KelvinTemperatureUnit()
    :
    TemperatureUnit(std::string("Kelvin"))

{

}

float KelvinTemperatureUnit::FromCelcius(float celcius) const
{
    return celcius - 273;
}
```

There are a number of flaws (that I know of) in the above:

- I'm not sure the `class TemperatureUnits{ ...    static std::list<TemperatureUnit> All();` pattern is the correct one to use, but unsure what would actually be better.
- By storing the types of TemperatureUnit in a std::list, they are treated as the base class TemperatureUnit, instead of their specialisations like KelvinTemperatureUnit. This means calling the FromCelcius method doesn't work correctly. I am pretty sure I used to do this type of thing using Java.
- I had a go, but it is probably pretty ugly and will offend someone :(

Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to go about this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am pretty sure I used to do this type of thing using Java.
```

Java objects are references. C++ objects are values. Simply convert to a reference, and then you will have more equivalent code. Oh, and a Java `list` is a C++ `vector`. A C++ `list` is a linked list.

Quite simply, do not bother to carry over any Java knowledge to C++, they are extremely different languages, you should start with C++ from scratch. C++ worth writing looks extremely different to Java.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<TemperatureUnit*> units;
    FahrenheitTemperatureUnit kFahrenheit;
    KelvinTemperatureUnit kKelvin;
    units.push_back(&kFahrenheit);
    units.push_back(&kKelvin);

    // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Also, on a more pedantic note: Your filenames are difficult to read. Instead of all one word in lowercase, try using underscores. I.e., "kelvintemperatureunit.h" becomes "kelvin_temperature_unit.h". This will make anyone who needs to maintain or extend your code very happy.

Answer (score 1):

The reason what you do works in Java is because all invocations are `virtual` or `static` in Java and objects are passed around using pointers rather than copies. which is not the case in C++.

This is because the `vtable` is not copied to the base class on you `All()` method. Thus you need to store rvalue references which requires C++0x compiler, or just pass pointers of the base class. Changes required are as follows:

```
static std::list<TemperatureUnit*> All():
```

The implementation would be:

```
std::list<TemperatureUnit*> TemperatureUnits::All()
{
    std::list<TemperatureUnit*> units;
    units.push_back(&TemperatureUnits::kFahrenheit);
    units.push_back(&TemperatureUnits::kKelvin);
    return units;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container of `TemperatureUnit` should be a container of `TemperatureUnit*`. In the former case, you have a container of *unspecialised instances* and the latter is a container of *interfaces*.

[Difference between Java and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the goal is here but why not just 1 Temperature class along the lines of?

```
class Temperature {

public:

  enum class TemperatureUnit {
    KELVIN,
    CELCIUS
  }

  Temperature( double value, TemperatureUnit unit );
  void set_value( double value, TemperatureUnit unit );
  double value( TemperatureUnit unit ) const;

private:

  double value_; // Always stored internally as KELVIN
};
```